# Django admin - override already registered model

Tags: python, django

I need to override [django-eav](https://github.com/mvpdev/django-eav) app admin class. In `eav/admin.py` model is registered: `admin.site.register(Value)`. I need to add *list_display* to this model. I know that it is bad practise to modify installed app code, so i need to override it. But, not sure how. In my own `app/admin.py` i have:

```
class EavValueAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'value_text', )

#unregistering class from eav.admin
admin.site.unregister(Value)
admin.site.register(Value, EavValueAdmin)
```

This gives me an error: **NotRegistered: The model Value is not registered**. 
If i try to comment this line: `admin.site.unregister(Value)`, also error: **AlreadyRegistered: The model Value is already registered**. How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django apps are loaded in the order they are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`. Therefore your `app` must come after `django-eav` to be able to unregister it:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [...
   'django-eav',
   ...
   'my_app',
]
```

Usually your apps must come after built-in and 3rd party apps. You have to test your project to see if everything works smoothly after changing the order.

Comment: Conversely, I've always been of the understanding that your apps should appear _before_ third-party and built-in apps. This means that templates and media can be overridden easier, amongst other things.

Comment: Meshy is correct. If your app overrides templates from django-eav then having your app appear after django-eav in INSTALLED_APPS breaks the default template resolution.

Comment: @hedleyroos It depends on your use case. As can be seen from this question, you can't deregister admin handlers if your app appears before django-eav. Even in that case you can always override templates using a dedicated template folder.