# How to add a field into a third party app model in Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm working with third party app - `django-quiz`. Since model `Quiz` itself doesn't contain field `Language`, I've added a `OneToOneField(Quiz)` into the `Language` model which is my own model.

In this app, you can see `Quizes` in your admin but I can't see  `Language` model choice field inside the `Quiz` tab (I can see the `Quiz` model choice inside the `Language` tab - I want opposite). How do I do that? I've tried to add to `admin.py` this code but It raises error (probably because It's a third party app)

```
from quiz.models import Quiz


class QuizInlineLanguage(admin.StackedInline):
    fields = Quiz.language

class QuizAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuizInlineLanguage,]

admin.site.unregister(Quiz)
admin.site.register(Quiz, QuizAdmin)
```

EDITED, ERROR:

```
<class 'SolnguagesApp.admin.QuizAdmin'>: (admin.E105) 'SolnguagesApp.admin.QuizInlineLanguage' must have a 'model' attribute.
```

Comment: remove this line, 
admin.site.unregister(Quiz)

Comment: That's the problem: django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Quiz is already registered, another thing is that QuizInlineLanguage is not correct too.

Comment: Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35741651/2011147

Answer (score 0):

Don't use unregistered before registering the model!

```
from quiz.models import Quiz


class QuizInlineLanguage(admin.StackedInline):
    fields = Quiz.language

class QuizAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuizInlineLanguage,]

admin.site.register(Quiz, QuizAdmin)
```

Comment: That's not working: django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Quiz is already registered And I suppose that QuizInlineLanguage is not correct too, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: The Quiz is not from this app, it's from third party app.

Comment: check the sequance of your app and thirdparty app, can you share your installed_Apps from your settings?

Comment: The quiz app was after myApp which was the problem. But, it does not solves the main problem. I want to be able to choose from Language instances inside the Quiz tab in admin.

Comment: The class QuizInlineLanguage and QuizAdmin is totally incorrect probably.