# hide django-allauth model from admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-allauth, django-3.1

I want hide all `django-allauth` model from admin page

[image]

after I see the source code in [github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py) I see it use three models `SocialAccount`, `SocialToken` and `SocialApp`.

now I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030038/13703933) to hide model from admin page and it works when I try to use it on my own model but
when I use it to hide `django-allauth` model it doesnt work, I think I stuck on the part `from x import SocialAccount, SocialToken, SocialApp`

because the error message is always like this

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SocialAccount' from 'x'
```

I dont know the `x` part what to import, where to import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount, SocialApp, SocialToken

admin.site.unregister(SocialAccount)
admin.site.unregister(SocialApp)
admin.site.unregister(SocialToken)
```

Comment: Note the order of apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741394/

Comment: works, as a note I have to change the app order on `INSTALLED_APPS`. I need to put all allauth apps above my app.